# How to get the firebase.User in AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using AngularFire2 (Ionic2) and Firebase Authentication.

I am having a problem trying to get the current user. The works for me, but inconsistently. Sometimes it is populated, and sometimes it is null.

```
let user: firebase.User = firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

Is there a way to get the current user more consistently?

**More Info:**

I am logging in as follows:

```
import { FirebaseAuth, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';

public auth: FirebaseAuth

    this.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Google,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup
    }).then((data: any) => {
            this.fireAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                        ....
            });
    });
```

Here the user is always populated. But where I need to get access to the user, is in another part of the code.

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I try use the following to get the current user:

```
    this.auth.subscribe((authData) => {
      let user = authData.auth;
        credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleIdToken, googleAccessToken);
        user.reauthenticate(credential).then(() => {...
    });
```

But then when I try create the credentials, I get the following error:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: reauthenticate failed: First
>   argument "credential" must be a valid credential.

When I get the current user in the first method, I don't get any errors and it works.

More info:

When I `console.log` the following `user` objects, they both look identical:

```
  let user: firebase.User = this.fireAuth.currentUser;
  console.log(user);
```

and

```
    this.auth.subscribe((authData) => {
            let user: firebase.User = authData.auth;
            console.log(user);
    });
```

but the one works (when not null) and the other cannot reauthenticate.

Comment: Why are you trying to `reauthenticate` when you're trying to `login`? How do you `reauthenticate` during a `login` process?

Answer (score 2):

Attention there is a new AngularFire Version. (4.0.0)

In the new version all the modules are split up. That means, you need to use the `AngularFireAuth`

```
    constructor(afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
        afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
          if(auth) {
            console.log('logged in');
          } else {
            console.log('not logged in');
          }
        });
    }
```

Hope I can help

Answer (score 1):

I find [this simple approach to work](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/137#issuecomment-211381227):

```
constructor(af: AngularFire) {
  af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
    if(auth) {
      console.log('logged in');
    } else {
      console.log('not logged in');
    }
  });
}
```

More on [AngularFire2 Authentication](https://github.com/seanmavley/AngularFire2-Authentication) on Github*

- Disclaimer: Project mine.