# Firebase: Keep user logged in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I use firebase and angularfire2 within an authentication system!

The problem is that after refresh the user needs to log in again! I need to avoid that issue so I found out that firebase gives me that option by using `authState`

but still not working!

This the code for the authService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/observable';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ToastMessagesService } from './toast-messages.service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  public user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  public userDetails: firebase.User = null;


  constructor(
    private af: AngularFireAuth,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private statusMessage: ToastMessagesService
  ) {

    this.user = af.authState;

    this.user.subscribe(
      user => this.userDetails = user
    )


  }

  async siginInRegular(username: string, password: string) {
    try {

      // const credentials = this.af.auth.email
      return await this.af.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).then(
        user => {
          if (user) {
            this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/home');
            this.statusMessage.message(`Welcome ${user.user.email}`);
          }
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.dir(error);
    }
  }

  async register(username: string, password: string) {
    try {
      return await this.af.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).then(
        user => {
          this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/profile');
          this.statusMessage.message(`Welcome ${user.user.email}`);
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.dir(error);
    }
  }

  signOut() {
    return this.af.auth.signOut();
  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return (this.userDetails != null) ? true : false;
  }


}
```

The guard code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {



  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private af: AngularFireAuth
  ) {

  }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {


    if (this.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true
    }

    console.log('Access denied!');
    return false;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase actually automatically will sign the user in when you reload the page. But since your handling of the sign-in is only in the `then()` block, it only happens when you explicitly sign them in.

To fix this, you want to use an `onAuthState` listener as shown in [get the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> ```
> firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
>   if (user) {
>     // User is signed in.
>   } else {
>     // No user is signed in.
>   }
> });
> ```

Unlike the `then()` handler, this `onAuthStateChanged` handler will be called every time the user's authentication state changes, including when you reload the page.

Since you're using AngularFire2, you can also use `af.auth.subscribe` as shown here: [How to get the firebase.User in AngularFire2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899746/how-to-get-the-firebase-user-in-angularfire2)

Comment: I do get the current logged in user with `af.authState.subscribe()` already but still after refreshing log out! what I'm guessing is the problem with the guard! 

You can take a look at the code I do use `this.user = af.authState` then I `subscribe` to it!

Comment: Ah, I missed that `this.user.subscribe( user => this.userDetails = user )` block. I'm definitely no expert on guards, so hope somebody else sees the problem there.

Comment: I get a response from the authState on the login page that a user is logged in but the guard sees that `userDetails` property is `undefined` or `null`!! 

if you looking inside the `isLoggedIn()` method the `userDetails` property is always null!